# Store the resulting rows of an SQL query in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am building an app in which I have a local sqlite database that I query.

For example,

```
char *query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Week = ? ORDER BY thematicallyRelated;";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(__db, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, weekSequence);

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        int sqlUniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        int sqlWeek = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
        int sqlNumber = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
        char *sqlTitle = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        bool sqlTextRelated = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        bool sqlThematicallyRelated = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);
        char *sqlRelatedElement = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

I will be using subsets of this data later on in the app, displayed in table views.

I'm wondering what the best object type is to store the resulting dataset so that I can retrieve rows with certain values, i.e. rows where `thematicallyRelated == true`.

Or would it be more efficient to execute several queries to retrieve the specific data I need for each table view?

Comment: An array of classes where each class has a property for each column.

Comment: Probably a NSDictionary, where you can retrieve data by key: [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"thematicallyRelated"];